# How to convert ArrayList<String> to JSON object using Jackson in Spring @ResponseBody

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Server layer will return a list of String value, like

```
{"Bob", "Charlotte", "Johnson", "David"...}
```

Now we need the List String to be a Json object to push to front end, like

```
[{id: "Bob"}, {id: "Charlotte"}, {id: "Johnson"}, {id: "David"...}]
```

or

```
[{name: "Bob"}, {name: "Charlotte"}, {name: "Johnson"}, {name: "David"...}]
```

Any label is fine, we just need a label to make it as JSON object. Does Jackson has something to convert List of String by default `i.e. {string: "Bob"}`? That will be really sweet......

Comment: We are using Jackson to convert lists of Objects (sometimes even Strings). By default it converts the List<String> to an array of strings by itself. As mentioned below, if you really want it to convert to an array of name/value pairs, you should return a list of objects with one String `name` (or `id` or whatever) property.

Comment: @Shadow Creeper Thanks, that's great, but if the converted array of string doesn't have a label, then how can the front end identify the value(as JSON object), especially want a label to handle list?

Comment: Our front end is a simple web app. We just iterate through the list. You can sort the list if you like, or add to it, remove from it, modify it. It is just an array, with a `length` and everything. You can do the normal for loop and reference it via `resultArray[index]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest thing to is to make your controller method return a structure that maps exactly to the JSON you want - for example a `List<SomeObject>` where `SomeObject` is a class with a `String id` field.

Comment: Thank you. Like you said I made an inner class with only one String field to hold the value, then made a list of this class object. Now it can be identified from front end.

Answer (score 1):

Th way of doing this is converting you List of String into a New Map.

Code :

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/mapping")
function mySpring()
{


            List<String> myStringList;
            Map<String,String> jsonMap= new LinkedHashMap<String,String>(); 
     // Use LinkedHashMap if you want to maintain order


    String key="id";        
     // Id or Name

            for (String myString: myStringList)
        {
        jsonMap.put(key,myString);

        }

return jsonMap;

}
```